# Safely passing ids to form action?

Tags: php, forms

Until now i have been using hidden fields in forms to pass data to the actions php. However i realise this is a massive security risk to the application and would like to be educated of the best method to currently passing form data from hidden fields in php?

```
<input type="hidden" value="sensitive_info">
```

Alex

Comment: it depends on the data, your approach may be fine, however **sessions** come to mind.

Comment: Don't use hidden inputs at all, unless you want the Client to be able to alter the data. Keep that information on the Server instead. By the way, your input would have to have a `name` attribute to work with PHP, unless you're using AJAX, which I recommend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think sessions are probably what you're looking for.

See http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp for a nice easy guide to using them.

You need `session_start();` at the very top of your php script, and then you can store information like so:

```
$_SESSION["stuff"] = "sensitive info";
```

Then simply access it on the next page with:

```
$stuff = $_SESSION["stuff"];
```

Simple :)

P.S. Make sure `session_start();` is at the top of every php script that uses the session variables.

Comment: I never really thought sessions for form data, is that the best method?

Comment: It's the most secure way of passing something from a front-end page to the back-end that is not user input, yeah. Bear in mind, if it's something like the IP address that you want to pass, or something that is generated with PHP, just use $_SERVER or whatever, on the back-end instead of using a session or hidden element.

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to use sessions for some reason, you can always encrypt the ID. This is probably not ultra secure, but will prevent all but the most determined from mucking with things.

```
<?php

define("KEY", "Something much more random than this");

function encrypt($key, $plaintext)
{
    $iv_size = openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-256-CBC');
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($iv_size);
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext,  'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    return base64_encode($iv . $ciphertext);
}

function decrypt($key, $ciphertext)
{
    $iv_size = openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-256-CBC');
    $ciphertext = base64_decode($ciphertext);
    $iv = substr($ciphertext, 0, $iv_size);
    return openssl_decrypt(substr($ciphertext, $iv_size), 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
}

$encrypted_id = encrypt(KEY, $database_id);
?>

<input name="foo" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $encrypted_id?>"/>
```